# Improving algorithm using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

The code below is written mainly using PHP, but I am hoping to speed up the process, and parsing strings in PHP is slow.

Assume the following where I get a string from the database, and converted it into an array.

```
$data['options_list'] = array(
            "Colours" => array('red','blue','green','purple'),
            "Length" => array('3','4','5','6'),
            "Voltage" => array('6v','12v','15v'),
        );
```

These subarrays will each be a dropdown Select list, an the end user can select exactly 1 from each of the select lists.

When the user hits submit, I will want to match the submitted values against a "price table" pre-defined by the admins. Potentially "red" and "6v" would cost $5, but "red" and "5"(length) and "6v" would cost $6.

**The question is, how to do so?**

Currently the approach I have taken is such:

Upon submission of the form (of the 3 select lists), I get the relevant price rules set by the admin from the database. I've made an example of results.

```
$data['price_table'] = 
            array(
                'red;4'=>'2',
                'red;5'=>'3',
                'red;6'=>'4',
                'blue;3'=>'5',
                'blue;4'=>'6',
                'blue;5'=>'7',
                'blue;6'=>'8',
                'green;3'=>'9',
                'green;4'=>'10',
                'green;5'=>'11',
                'green;6'=>'12',
                'purple;3'=>'13',
                'purple;4'=>'14',
                'purple;5'=>'15',
                'purple;6'=>'16',
                'red;3'=>'1',
                'red;3;12v'=>'17',
                'blue;6;15v'=>'18',
        );
```

*Note : The order of the above example can be of any order, and the algorithm should work.*

I then explode each of the above elements into an array, and gets the result that matches the best score.

```
$option_choices = $this->input->post('select');
$score = 0;
        foreach($data['price_table'] as $key=>$value)
        {
            $temp = 0;
            $keys = explode(';',$key);

            foreach($keys as $k)
            {
                if(in_array($k, $option_choices))
                {
                    $temp++;
                }else{
                    $temp--;
                }               
            }
            if($temp > $score)
            {
                $score = $temp;
                $result = $value;
            }           
        }
        echo "Result : ".$result;
```

---

**Examples of expected results:**

Selected options: "red","5"
Result: 3

Selected Options: "3", "red"
Result: 1

Selected Options: "red", "3", "12v"
Result: 17

---

The current method works as expected. However, handling these using PHP is slow. I've thought of using JSON, but that would mean that I would be giving the users my whole price table, which isn't really what I am looking for. I have also thought of using another language, (e.g python) but it wouldn't particularly be practical considering the costs. That leaves me with MySQL.

If someone can suggest a cheap and cost-efficient way to do this, please provide and example. Better still if you could provide an even better PHP solution to this which works fast.

Thank you!

Comment: Optimizing array logic in PHP is hard, let's go shopp- hang on, context for this? is this magento or something? (also, `explode()` and give each part a numeric value with a meaning)

Comment: sorry. I'm using CodeIgniter for this

Comment: I think the matching algorithm you're using will be inefficient in any language. It doesn't look like it be indexed, it has to calculate a score for every row.

Comment: is there any other method you would suggest then? The problem is that I wouldn't know how the rules will be set, nor would I know how the input would be given

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did work to make the results read faster but you're still parsing and testing every array part against the full list?  This would probably run faster moving the search to MySQL and having extra columns there.

Since you can control the array (or test string) perhaps try fixed length strings:

```
$results = explode("\n", "
1         Red       v1
22        Blue      v2
333       Green     v3");

$i = 0;
while($i < count($results)) {
    $a = substr($results[$i], 0, 10);
    $b = substr($results[$i], 10, 20);
    $c = substr($results[$i], strpos(' ', strrev($results[$i]))-1);
    if(stripos($userInput, $a . $b . $c) !== false) {
            // parse more...
```

Supposedly JavaScript is good at this with memoizaion:
http://addyosmani.com/blog/faster-javascript-memoization/

Comment: I dont actually have control over the test string, as they would be generated from the original `options_list`, which is set by the admin. Secondly, as I mentioned, I am not looking for a javascript solution as it would mean that the end user would get access to the price table, which is in this case, a security breach

Comment: Then you'll need to do the work of rewriting your array searches and testing speed.

Comment: which is exactly what I am asking here